# chrome.storage not saving data properly

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, opera

I have an options array:

```
    settings: {
        'magnify': false,
        'nobinds': true,
        'nospoiler': false,
        'replies': true,
        'stickies': true,
        'autogif': true,
        'autowebm': true,
        'resamplewebm': false,
        'archives': true,
        'linkifier': true,
        'menu': ''
    },
```

I save/get the data like this:

```
    loadSettings: function() {
        chrome.storage.local.get(Board.settings, function(items) {
            console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
            console.log(items);

            Board.settings = items;

            for(var key in Board.settings) {
                console.log("loaded [" + key + "] = " + Board.settings[key] + " - \"" + items[key] + "\"");

                if(typeof(Board.settings[key]) == 'boolean') {
                    Board.switchCheckboxAttribute($('#theme-' + key), Board.settings[key]);
                } else if(typeof(Board.settings[key]) == 'string') {
                    $('#theme-' + key).val(Board.settings[key]);
                }
            }
        });
    },

    saveSettings: function() {
        chrome.storage.local.set(Board.settings, function() {
            console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);

            $('#theme-msg').html("Done").attr("class", "msg-ok").show().delay(2E3).fadeOut(500);

            Board.applySettings();
        });
    },

    switchCheckboxAttribute: function(obj, active) {
        console.log('switchCheckboxAttribute(' + obj.attr('id') + ', ' + active + ')');

        if(active){ 
            obj.addClass('active');
            obj.html("&#x2714;");
        } else {
            obj.removeClass('active');
            obj.html('');
        }
    },
```

Console output:

```
undefined board.js:74
Object {archives: true, autogif: true, autowebm: true, linkifier: true, magnify: false…} board.js:75
loaded [archives] = true - "true" board.js:80
switchCheckboxAttribute(theme-archives, true) board.js:107
loaded [autogif] = true - "true" board.js:80
switchCheckboxAttribute(theme-autogif, true) board.js:107
loaded [autowebm] = true - "true" board.js:80
switchCheckboxAttribute(theme-autowebm, true) board.js:107
loaded [linkifier] = true - "true" board.js:80
switchCheckboxAttribute(theme-linkifier, true) board.js:107
loaded [magnify] = false - "false" board.js:80
switchCheckboxAttribute(theme-magnify, false) board.js:107
loaded [menu] =  - "" board.js:80
loaded [nobinds] = true - "true" board.js:80
switchCheckboxAttribute(theme-nobinds, true) board.js:107
loaded [nospoiler] = false - "false" board.js:80
switchCheckboxAttribute(theme-nospoiler, false) board.js:107
loaded [replies] = true - "true" board.js:80
switchCheckboxAttribute(theme-replies, true) board.js:107
loaded [resamplewebm] = false - "false" board.js:80
switchCheckboxAttribute(theme-resamplewebm, false) board.js:107
loaded [stickies] = true - "true" board.js:80
switchCheckboxAttribute(theme-stickies, true) board.js:107
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. jquery.min.js:3
switchCheckboxAttribute(theme-resamplewebm, true) board.js:107
undefined
```

The last runtime error is undefined both times, but when I save data and reload, the saved array stays the same (default). Am I handling this incorrectly?

Comment: Did you try to pass in `null` as first parameter to `chrome.storage.local.get`? This should get you the entire content of the storage

Comment: I changed it to null, and the result is Object {archives: true, autogif: true, autowebm: true, linkifier: true, magnify: false…} so the entire array is returning, but save does not seem to make anything actually change.

Comment: Okay, update, I solved it. I noticed during my checkbox onclick function, I didn't actually change the value of the array despite changing the value of the visible checkbox. I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Turns out I was updating the visible checkbox on jQuery click, but I did not update the settings value so it did not change, and the change was not recorded when saved.